# How to create a simple proximity alert?

Tags: proximity

Ive looked around but cant seem to find a clear answer so so far I have nothing. Can someone please help me create a simple proximity alert for Android so it then pops up a yes/no question with the "yes" taking it to another screen and "no" exiting the program.

Some examples would be really helpful and if you could please say which part in Eclipse its supposed to go into because Im really new to this and a lot of people just put some code and dont say where it goes, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: At first, set the scene for those who want to help you: What language/technology are you using? What did you try yourself and what didn´t work?

Comment: oops sorry I forgot, updated it now, thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 2):

To build an Android app with proximity alert, the main ingredient are Broadcast Receiver, Intent, PendingIntent, and AddProximityAlert.

The workflow should be as following: -

1. Register an IntentFilter with a Broadcast Receiver
2. Create an Intent
3. Get a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast
4. Set proximity alert

You can check out [my post](http://moretin.tumblr.com/post/14215975978/developing-proximity-alert-app-for-android-part-1) on this topic.